# How to check if a python function is a method or not before it is bounded to an object?

Tags: python

I have a class like this

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def run(self):
        pass
```

if we look at the type of `run` it is a function. I am now writing a decorator and this decorator should be used with either a stand alone function or a method but has different behavior if the function it is decorating is a method. When registering the method `run`, the decorator cannot really tell if the function is a method because it has not been bounded to an object yet. I have tried `inspect.ismethod` and it also does not work. Is there a way that I can detect `run` is a method in my decorator instead of a standalone function? Thanks!

To add a bit more info:

Basically I am logging something out. If it is decorating an object method, I need the name of the class of that object and the method name, if it is the decorating a function, I just need the function name.

Comment: what does inspect.ismethod() and inspect.isfunction returns?

Comment: you could check if `run` is in the global namespace but why do you want to do this? `run` is still a function here, just one bound to your class

Comment: What exactly does your decorator want to do with the difference? When the decorator is called, `run` is *always* a function; whether you get a method depends on how `run` is accessed. `A.run` is a function; `A().run` is a method. The exact details are specified by the descriptor protocol, because `function` implements `__get__`.

Comment: @chepner Isn't `A.run` a class method, or is that only if it's decorated with `@classmethod`?

Comment: I see that `inspect.classify_class_attrs(A)` returns `run` slot as `Attribute` which is marked as "method", it's function has the same address as `A.run`, maybe it can helps

Comment: Basically I am logging something out. If it is decorating an object method, I need the name of the class of that object and the method name, if it is the decorating a function, I just need the function name. @chepner

Comment: Why not simply have two decorators, one for a standalone function, a different one for a method/function defined in a class.

Comment: @barny if in the end there is no way then I will do that

Comment: @wjandrea `A.run` is just a class *attribute*; if that attribute defines `__get__` (as the `function` type does), `A.run` evaluates to `A.run.__get__(None, A)`. The `@classmethod` decorator essentially creates a new object with a *different* definition of `__get__`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentionned by chepner, a function only becomes a method when it's used as such - i.e. when it's looked up on an instance, and resolved on the class. What you are decorating is, and will always be, a function (well, unless you already decorated it with something that returns another `callable` type of course, c.f. the `classmethod` type).

At this point you have two options: the safe and explicit one, or the "unsafe guessing game" one.

The safe and explicit solution is, simply, to have two distinct decorators, one for plain functions, and another for "functions to be used as methods".

The unsafe guessing game one is to inspect the function's first arg name (using `inspect.getargspecs()`) and consider it's a "function to be used as method" if the first argument is named "self".

Obviously, the safe and explicit solution is also much simpler ;-)